# Convergence in distribution example

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I have a trouble understanding how below is true:

[image]

I have drawn $F_{\frac{Y_n}{n}} (y)$ above. Is this correct?

Now, if I send n to infinity, I still get the same graph (discrete) and not the distribution function of continuous uniform [0,1]?

Comment: No, your graph isn't correct for $n > 1$.  For instance, take $n=3$.  Then $P(Y_3/3 \le 1/2) = P(Y_3 \le 3/2) = 1/3$, but according to your graph it would be 0.  Try again to draw the correct graph, and I think it will become more clear why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have drawn $F_{\frac{Y_n}{n}} (y)$ above. Is this correct?

No, the CDF of $Y_n/n$ is a stairway from altitude $0$ to altitude $1$ made of $n$ steps of height $1/n$ from each $(k-1)/n$ to each $k/n$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$.

Hence the pointwise convergence of $F_{Y_n/n}$ to the CDF $F:x\mapsto\max(\min(x,1),0)$ of the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.